# Css Libs Update Sass . How update libs with SASS but without lose customize

Tags: css, sass, uikit

I'm a novice with SASS and I'm using a customised uikit. But uikit have a lot of updates. I started using uikit 3 when it was at v17.

I want to know how do i deal with customize and updates of uikits.

Obs: Some customise is easy only import pre-existent hooks at source and compile. This scenario is OK. I can update libs without problems. Just follow [doc](https://getuikit.com/docs/sass%22).

But in some other cases, hooks is suggestions [comented](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/develop/src/scss/components/table.scss#L275). I need do have some modifications at source to add suggestions modification.  Add this @mixin hook-table(){} above [line 71](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/develop/src/scss/components/table.scss#L71)

Comment: [2] https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/develop/src/scss/components/table.scss#L71

Comment: [3] "https://getuikit.com/docs/sass"

Comment: Welcome to SO please watch your Grammer and meaning i have tried to correct not sure if it's 100%, also use the Hyper links system and do not add links that are part of your question into the comments for the quest.

Comment: @MartinBarker, about the links at comment. I'm novice at stackoverflow too. And I can only publish one link.